# How to implement is empty for a Node class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tree, avl-tree

I have the following code for representation of nodes of a tree:

```
public class Node {

/**
 * All the attributes.
 * @param value: the generic value assigned to this node.
 * @param leftNode: the left leaf of this node.
 * @param rightNode: the right leaf of this node.
 */
private Map map;
private Node leftNode;
private Node rightNode;

/**
 * Constructor Node. 
 * Creates a node with it's leafs being null.
 * @param map 
 */
public Node(Map map){
    this(map, null, null);
}


/**
 * Constructor Node.
 * Creates a node with it's leafs assigned accordingly.
 * @param value
 * @param left_node
 * @param right_node 
 */
public Node(Map value, Node left_node, Node right_node){
    this.leftNode = left_node;
    this.rightNode = right_node;
    this.map = value;
}

/**
 * Returns the value of the node.
 * @return 
 */
public Map getValue(){
    return this.map;
}

/**
 * Returns the left child of the node.
 * @return 
 */
public Node getLeftChild(){
    return this.leftNode;
}

/**
 * Returns the right child of the node.
 * @return 
 */
public Node getRightChild(){
    return this.rightNode;
}

/**
 * Removes the value of the node and returns the value.
 * @return 
 */
public Map removeValue(){
    Map temp = this.map;
    this.map = null;
    return temp;
}

/**
 * Removes the left child of the node and returns the child node.
 * @return 
 */
public Node removeLeftChild(){
    Node temp = this.leftNode;
    this.leftNode = null;
    return temp;
}

/**
 * Removes the right child of the node and returns the child node.
 * @return 
 */
public Node removeRightChild(){
    Node temp = this.rightNode;
    this.rightNode = null;
    return temp;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the node to a given value.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the value is empty
 * @param map 
 */
public void setValue(Map map){
    if (this.map == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value is empty.");
    this.map = map;
}

/**
 * Sets the left child of the node to a given node.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the node is empty
 * @param node 
 */
public void setLeftChild(Node node){
    if (node.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The node is empty.");
    this.leftNode = node;
}

/**
 * Sets the right child of the node to a given node.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the node is empty
 * @param node 
 */
public void setRightChild (Node node){
    if (node.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The node is empty.");
    this.rightNode = node;
}

/**
 * Checks if the following Node is empty.
 * Node can be null or it's value being null for it to be empty.
 * @return 
 */
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (this == null){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
}
```

However, when I try runing the following code (I have tested other cases and my tree works) this will give me a NullPointerException.

In main

```
{...
Node test2_2 = new Node(new Map<> (5, 2));
System.out.println("Object left child is: " + test2_2.getLeftChild().isEmpty());
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainPackage.Main.main(Main.java:35)
C:\Users\mehrz\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Anny suggestions?

Comment: Well, it's a new node, so obviously you haven't put anything in `leftChild`, and when you try to call `isEmpty()` on the `null` value, you get NPE.

Comment: I also question putting a `Map` inside a node.  That seems wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I am using a double pointer node to represent branches of the tree. I got it :-) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor, you put null for Node attribute instead adapt your constructor by:

```
/**
 * Constructor Node. 
 * Creates a node with it's leafs being null.
 * @param map 
 */
public Node(Map map){
    this(map, new Node(), new Node());
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have a no-argument ctor for `Node`.

Comment: I have tried this beforehand. Because I don't have a constructor
Node(){} it does not work.